# log4j2 deleting old archived logs not working

Tags: logging, log4j, log4j2

I was trying to delete old archived log files automatically via log4j.xml. However, it appears to be not working with my current configuration. I am using rollingfileappender's custom delete.

```
    <RollingFile name="AppRollingFile" fileName="${logHome}/anow.log"
      filePattern="${logHome}/arch/$${date:yyyy-MM}/app-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i.log.gz">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>${fullPattern}</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        **<SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>**
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        **<Delete basePath="${logHome}/logs/arch" maxDepth="4">
          <IfFileName glob="*/app-*.log.gz" />
          <IfLastModified age="10d" />
        </Delete>**
      </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
      <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
    </RollingFile>
```

In the snippet above, I assume that it would remove archive older than 10 days. However, the archives persists. Given that it is February 19 today, it should remove the following files.

```
sh-4.2$ pwd; ls -lrt
/app/anow/logs/arch/2021-01
total 1441664
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  10354093 Jan  2 00:00 anow-2021-01-01-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  66830028 Jan  3 00:00 anow-2021-01-02-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006 118353830 Jan  3 01:53 anow-2021-01-03-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  19946445 Jan  7 00:00 anow-2021-01-06-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  24558293 Jan  8 00:00 anow-2021-01-07-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  26325656 Jan  9 00:00 anow-2021-01-08-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  24219865 Jan 10 00:00 anow-2021-01-09-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  24321364 Jan 11 00:00 anow-2021-01-10-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  26148340 Jan 12 00:00 anow-2021-01-11-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  28556190 Jan 13 00:00 anow-2021-01-12-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  25096070 Jan 14 00:00 anow-2021-01-13-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  19412396 Jan 15 00:00 anow-2021-01-14-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  36375727 Jan 16 00:00 anow-2021-01-15-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  37948374 Jan 17 00:00 anow-2021-01-16-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  41469159 Jan 18 00:00 anow-2021-01-17-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  46600145 Jan 19 00:00 anow-2021-01-18-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  60242290 Jan 20 00:00 anow-2021-01-19-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  52262451 Jan 21 00:00 anow-2021-01-20-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  58501838 Jan 22 00:00 anow-2021-01-21-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  58811286 Jan 23 00:00 anow-2021-01-22-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  59832654 Jan 24 00:00 anow-2021-01-23-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  62842420 Jan 25 00:00 anow-2021-01-24-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  67862898 Jan 26 00:00 anow-2021-01-25-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  33771039 Jan 27 00:00 anow-2021-01-26-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  75302472 Jan 28 00:00 anow-2021-01-27-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  77243585 Jan 29 00:00 anow-2021-01-28-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  79226811 Jan 30 00:00 anow-2021-01-29-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006  97272890 Jan 31 00:00 anow-2021-01-30-1.log.gz
-rw-r--r--. 1 1001 2006 116568611 Feb  1 00:01 anow-2021-01-31-1.log.gz
```

I don't know what I am missing